# Как можно импортировать c++ функцию из dll с помощью ctypes и можно ли?

Tags: python, c++, dll, g++, ctypes

Есть код на c++ ( `lib1.cpp` ), скомпилированный в dll файл ( `lib1.dll` ), также python код ( `main.py` ). Для компиляции dll файла использован `g++ mingw 12.2.0`. Использую Windows 10

Код компиляции:

```
g++ -shared -o lib1.dll lib1.cpp
```

main.py :

```py
import ctypes
lib=ctypes.CDLL("lib1.dll",winmode=0)
lib.print("Hello")
```

lib1.cpp :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" {
    void print(string st);
}

void print(string st){
    cout<<st;
}
```

Я видел в решении похожей задаче на английской версии сайта, там использовался `extern`. В моем случае он не помог. При попытке запустить функцию `print` , я получаю ошибку

```py
AttributeError: function 'print' not found
```

Как можно подключить функцию и можно ли? Если нет, то почему в [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44211194/c-function-in-python-from-dll-using-ctypes-function-not-found-and-access-vi) случае всё получилось?

PS: Немного исправил код lib1.cpp

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь все дело как раз в `-static`  т.е. есть разница между статической и динамической библиотекой, но по идее и не статическую библиотеку можно подключить. Попробуйте пока с флагом `-static`, напишите выйдет или нет, если что у меня возможно получится глянуть как это сделать.

Comment: @DaniilLoban , с `-static` всё тоже самое

Comment: Такое ощущение, что с С++ вы не знакомы. Объявление должно быть перед определением и сигнатура совпадать. Хотя в данном случае отдельное объявление и не нужно даже. Кроме того, С интерфейс не позволяет передавать объекты `std::string`.

Comment: @user7860670 С c++ я знаком (не знаком конкретно с командой extern), а исправления кода по вашим советам мне не помогло. Функция всё еще не видна для ctypes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно. Решение найдено на основе этой [статьи](https://habr.com/ru/articles/466499/) где есть пример с использованием класса. Для простоты я оставил только код присутсвующий в вопросе. В качестве запуска на питоне я проверил еще и метод из [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44230242/6750422) — оба работают, второй разумеется проще. хотя если нужны `перегрузки` то возможно пригодится и первый, не проверял. Что касается [extern](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/extern-cpp?view=msvc-170) то в данном случае, как я понял, он помогает сохранить имена функций такими как мы их прописали, вероятно чтобы `ctypes` мог с ним работать.

`lib1.hpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    void print(char *val);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

`lib1.cpp`

```
#include "lib1.hpp"

void print(char *val) {
    std::cout << val << std::endl;
}
```

`main.py`

```
# Вариант с Хабра 

import ctypes
lib1 = ctypes.CDLL('./lib1.so')
lib1.print.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
lib1.print.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]
lib1.print('Hello!'.encode('utf-8')) # Hello!

# Вариант из ответа enSO

from ctypes import cdll
lib1 = cdll.LoadLibrary('./lib1.so')
lib1.print('Hello!'.encode('utf-8')) # Hello!
```

*Если не передавать с `encode('utf-8')` вывод стопорится на 1 символе.*

Тестировал только на `linux` (`.so` аналог `.dll`) код компилировал так:

```
g++ -fPIC -shared -o lib1.so lib1.cpp
```

Флаг `-fPIC` позволяет генерировать машинный код не зависимо от адреса размещения программы в памяти, без него у меня при компиляции вылетала ошибка

```
symbol `_ZSt4cout@@GLIBCXX_3.4' can not be used when making a shared object;
recompile with -fPIC
```

Т.е. лучше все же эту опцию использовать если будет ругаться.`

**P.S.**:

В `Windows 10`, все таки удалось проверить, код отрабатывает, поменял только `.so` на `.dll` (в билде и скрипте) и добавил аргумент `winmode=0` в `ctypes.CDLL`, т.е. так как у Вас.

```
lib=ctypes.CDLL("lib1.dll",winmode=0)
```